# Unsupported parameter type Integer. Valid invocable parameters must be List types like List<T> where T is a supported type

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I am trying to call this apex class from a flow but I run to this error, can anyone show me a better way to write this? Thanks

```
global class NameGenerator {
        
        @InvocableMethod
        public static String generateRandomString(Integer len) {
            final String chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            randStr = '';
            while (randStr.size() < len) {
                Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
                randStr += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
            
                }
            return randStr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I believe the negative reaction here is once again due to a lack of effort and research. The error message you're getting is telling you _precisely what is wrong and how to fix it_.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below [considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) for Invocable method for input parameters.

> **There can be at most one input parameter and its data type must be one of the following:**
>
> 1. A list of a primitive data type or a list of lists of a primitive
>    data type – the generic Object type is not supported.
> 2. A list of an sObject type or a list of lists of an sObject type.
> 3. A list of the generic sObject type (List) or a list of
>    lists of the generic sObject type (List<List>).
> 4. A list of a user-defined type, containing variables of the supported
>    types or user-defined Apex types, with the InvocableVariable annotation. Create a custom global or public Apex class to implement your data type, and make sure that your class contains at least one member variable with the invocable variable annotation.

As you are passing Inter as input parameter it is causing the issue. You need to pass `List<Integer>` as input and take the integer value from the list in the code.

Comment: Please don't use `{}` for quotes, unless it is actually code. I have taken the liberty of fixing it for you this time.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Thanks for fixing it. I will take care of this from next time.