How to fix an unusual error from a flow that is called from apex class
I have a flow that closes a Gift Commitment if the action {!action} is equal to "close". This flow calls a standard invocable method called "Close Gift Commitment" (from NPC) and needs only one input, the Gift Commiment Id.
I verified that the Gift commiment id and the action has the right values in it. I even tried debugging the flow and it succeeded. But when I tried calling the flow from an apex class like in the following lines of code, it throws an unusual error: FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR class java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double (java.math.BigDecimal and java.lang.Double are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap').
The autolaunched flow only contains 2 elements:

Decision - {!action} equals close
Invocable - Close Gift Commitment (Parameters is Gift Commitment record id)


There are only two resources in the flow:

{!action} - it is a text and with no default value and enabled as input variable
{!giftCommitmentId} - it is a text and with no default value and enabled as input variable

Note: No other resources in the flow



I even tried it in developer console with static values, but still throws error:


Note: I have verified that the values passed to the flow are correct.
Apex code:
Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
params.put('giftCommitmentId', String.valueOf(giftCommitmentId));
params.put('action', 'close');

Flow.Interview.Sample_Flow_Api_Name flow = new Flow.Interview.Sample_Flow_Api_Name(params);
flow.start();


I believe your question is a duplicate of this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/380443/unsupported-parameter-type-integer-valid-invocable-parameters-must-be-list-type

@BenjaminPirih That question is referring to a custom Invocable method. In my case, I am using a standard invocable method from NPC.

Just because it is from a package doesn't make it standard; it's still custom from the Salesforce platform perspective. That said, such a problem is unlikely to exist in the package.

I think you need to provide more detail about your flow, rather than the invocable method. What resources does the flow contain? How many variables are defined as available for input? Do you have some other resources being used when calling the invocable method? Please [edit] the question to add detail for your flow. Start with a screenshot of the flow editor, then show the detail of the entry conditions, the resources defined and how the invocable method is called.

@PhilW It just contains 2 elements. 1 is a decision that contains {!action} equals close and the invocable that passes only 1 parameter which is the Gift Commitment Id.

This is either something in your flow that you have not documented here, another value that the invocable method receives that is defaulting wrongly or a platform bug. But without clarity I don't think we can determine which.

@PhilW I don't really know what you mean by "not documented". The flow is really simple. I added a screenshot on my question.

Nonprofit Cloud is very new. You should check with support to see if there are any issues with the method you are calling.

Also you have an apex class executing a flow that calls invocable Apex - is there any way you can simplify this?

@DavidCheng We already submitted a case to support but so far no update yet. My initial solution was to use the invocable apex direct in my class but I tried looking for the invocable apex class but couldn't find it, I even tried retrieving the flow's metadata to be able to see which class it is, but it doesn't show there.

By "not documented" I meant some declared and initialized but otherwise unused resource, for example. Or some weirdness in how you have declared the resource you do use (the ID variable).

@PhilW There only 2 variables in the flow. 1 is the action which is a text, 2 is the giftCommitmentId which is also a text. No other variables in my flow as it is a new flow that I created. Also, I've already mention in the question that I've tested debugging the flow and it worked. The problem only exist when I call the flow from apex whether it is in a class or even in developer console.

Fair enough. Probably a platform issue then.
